# MIT Kerberos not applying password expiration upon user creation

Tags: kerberos, mit-kerberos

I'm running MIT Kerberos 1.17-3 on Debian 10 for a new auth system to replace our old Kerberos setup and noticed an odd issue. When creating user principals with kadmin it is not setting a password expiration date, but if I then change the password the expiration date is set. I can add the `-pwexpire` flag and get it to set the expiration during creation, but I would prefer that not be necessary in case either myself or a coworker forgets to set that flag when creating new users.

Is there a way to force Kerberos to set a password expiration date during the user creation without having to specify `-pwexpire`? Thanks in advance!

```
kadmin.local:  getpol default
Policy: default
Maximum password life: 90 days 00:00:00 #<---- Max password life set correctly in policy 
<snip>
```

```
kadmin.local:  addprinc test123
NOTICE: no policy specified for test123@example.COM; assigning "default" #<---- default policy being applied during creation
Enter password for principal "test123@example.COM": 
Re-enter password for principal "test123@example.COM": 
Principal "test123@example.COM" created.
```

```
kadmin.local:  getprinc test123
Principal: test123@example.COM
Expiration date: [never]
Last password change: Mon Jun 29 11:57:49 MDT 2020
Password expiration date: [never]  #<-------------- Password expiration set to "never" after creation
<snip>
Policy: default
```

```
kadmin.local:  cpw test123
Enter password for principal "test123@example.COM": 
Re-enter password for principal "test123@example.COM": 
Password for "test123@example.COM" changed.
```

```
kadmin.local:  getprinc test123
Principal: test123@example.COM
Expiration date: [never]
Last password change: Mon Jun 29 11:58:16 MDT 2020
Password expiration date: Sun Sep 27 11:58:16 MDT 2020 #<--- Expiration updated to policy setting after changing password
<snip>
Policy: default
```

Comment: Just a thought: if you had set a temp password that users have to change on their 1st login, then it  would make sense to never expire the temp password. Maybe that's the expected behaviour nowadays...